# Eigen Values and Probability Question. Not for the faint of heart

Tags: probability, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the below question:
Background: There are 3 cities, K, W and G. When in W, the probability of the tourist going to K=p, G=0 and W= 1-p. When in K, probabilityfor G=p, W=1-p , and k=0. When in G, k=1-p,W= 0 and G=p. 
Question to answer: Assuming the start of the trip in W, what are the probabilities of being in W, K or G after n days? Using a *closed form formula.

My Attempt: I know that we get a matrix below which can be reduced using eigen values. However, the below matrix is not symmetrical so can there be a closed form formula?  Closed form formulas are generally only for Toeplitz or symmetrical matrices (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrices)
We get a non-symmetrical matrix of 
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1-p & 1-p & 0 \\
    p & 0 & 1-p \\
    0 & p & p \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

My attempt: I found these to be the 3 eigen values of 1 and +√((ρ-ρ^2) )and -√((ρ-ρ^2) )
**Is the answer just the decomposed matrix** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix)
Which is made up of the eigen vectors formed by the eigen values which are
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    p/(1-p) & \frac{p-1-\sqrt{p-p^2}}{(1-p)} & \frac{\sqrt{ρ-ρ^2}+p-1}{1-p} \\
    \frac{P^2}{(1-p)^2} & \frac{\sqrt{p-p^2}+1-p}{(1-p)(p+\sqrt{p-p^2})} & \frac{\sqrt{p-p^2}-1+p}{(1-p)(p-\sqrt{p-p^2})} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

If you need me to update, tell me.

EDIT: So I noticed that there is actually no solution for the Jordan decomposition. I think this is because the roots are complex
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & \sqrt{p-p^2} & -\sqrt{p-p^2} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$ 
Is this a correct conclusion.

Comment: Please use MathJax to type up your question

Comment: Hint:Markov Chain

Comment: If your transition matrix is $P$, then given that  it's 3-dimensional and you've found 3 distinct eigenvalues, you can write $P^n=U\Lambda^n U^*$, it's Jordan decomposition. Then you can solve for the associated probabilities by supplying the initial starting point.

Comment: Hi Alex R, would Pn then be equal to the probability over a fixed term n, i.e would it be a closed form formula

Comment: “Closed form formulas are generally only for ...” Nonsense. If you can find the Jordan decomposition of the matrix, you can find a closed form for its powers. In this case, the matrix is diagonalizable, so it’s even easier.

Comment: Any chance I can get a solution then. I read that closed end formulas are only for diagonisable matrices. So does that mean that if P=[1-p 1-p 0/ p 0 1-p/ 0 p p] then   Pn=UΛnU∗, that the matrix U is the answer to the question